# apt-get Post-hook for specific package

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

So I found a clever way to get Firefox to look at the system CA certificates. This involves replacing `/usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so` with a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so`. This works perfectly, except when Firefox is updated by `apt`.

I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236833/apt-hook-to-check-for-specific-package-changes) answer that suggested the usage of `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs`, however from what I understand about that, is it works only *before* the package is installed/updated, whereas I need something similar for *after* Firefox is updated. But I could not find anything in `man apt.conf` that might work.

So basically, is there a way I can create a post-update/installation hook for a specific package?

Comment: I see you have a Debian tag. Look at Debian diversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Rui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138261/rui-f-ribeiro) [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479420/apt-get-post-hook-for-specific-package#comment876604_479420), you should use a diversion for this rather than a hook. A diversion will instruct `dpkg` to install a given file with another name instead, leaving you to handle the original name as you wish:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so.orig --rename --local /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
```

(yes, the syntax seems back-to-front).

From then on, `dpkg` won’t overwrite `libnssckbi.so`, but will instead install any updates to that file as `libnssckbi.so.orig` instead. Your link will remain in place.